# How to pass parameters to a function that is getting triggered by an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the problem is I have an event listener and a function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function insert_hint(element, string){
        console.log(string);
    }

    $('.test').on('click', insert_hint('123', '123'));

});
```

But If I do it like this, it instantly triggers my function, instead of waiting for the element with class 'test' to be clicked.

How can I prevent it from happening and what is a proper way to pass parameters to a function that is being triggered on an event?

I have a feeling that it's something very obvious and easy, but I'm just missing it.

Comment: Wrap it in another function.

Comment: Why would you spend time writing this question instead of just typing the title into google where there are already thousands of answers to it? -1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$('.test').on('click', function() {
    insert_hint('123', '123'); 
});
```

Passing the function inside the click callback function.

More details here: [.on() jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: 11 upvotes on an answer (which does not use the correct terminology) to a question so simple it should not have been asked at all... What is SO coming to! :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap the function into another function, which will specify its' arguments.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function insert_hint(element, string){
        console.log(string);
    }

    $('.test').on('click', function() {
        insert_hint('123', '123');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Outside of wrapping it into an anonymous function like @palash and @ralh demonstrated, you can also use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function insert_hint(element, string, evt){
        console.log(element, string, evt); // "hello", "world", the click event
    }

    $('.test').on('click', insert_hint.bind(this, 'hello', 'world'));

});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8nahor6L/